# I need help for making my c# windows form project which contains about 8 forms switch between languages using combo box or something that can switch

Tags: c#, localization, .net-assembly, windows-forms-designer

So , I created this visual studio project using c# and SQL server manager and the system windows form contains about 9 forms / pages and I need to make a selection of languages that I can select from in the login form that switches the whole language of the system when a language is selected and I login (the system have so many forms and I want to change thier language together through one selection)

I tried localizing every single form and then trying to connect the switcher to all forms ,and I tried a lot of tutorials on YouTube and chrome an tried using chat gpt but nothing worked.

Comment: the program will use the system information about language and select automatically the language